# error: no matching function for call to ‘BSTreeNode<int, int>::BSTreeNode(int, int, NULL, NULL)’ - what's wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

> error: no matching function for call
>   to ‘BSTreeNode::BSTreeNode(int, int, NULL,
>   NULL)’
>
> candidates are: BSTreeNode::BSTreeNode(KF, DT&,
>   BSTreeNode*, BSTreeNode*) [with KF = int, DT = int]

here is how I used it:

```
BSTreeNode<int, int> newNode(5,9, NULL, NULL) ;
```

I defined it as follows:

```
BSTreeNode(KF sKey, DT &data, BSTreeNode *lt, BSTreeNode *rt):key(sKey),dataItem(data), left(lt), right(rt){}
```

what's wrong with using my constructor this way?

i've been pulling out my hair all night please help me ASAP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-const references can't be bound to an rvalue, which is what you're trying to do with the argument `9` for the `DT &data` parameter.

You'll either need to pass in a variable that has the value `9`, or you'll need to change the argument (and the `dataItem` member if it's a reference) to be `DT` type that gets copied by value into the object. Even if you change the reference to be `const` to get rid of the compiler error, you'll have an issue with the lifetime of the argument that's passed in if it's a temporary (it won't live past the constructor call, so you'll be left with a dangling reference).

Here's a small example program that demonstrates the problem with binding a const reference in an object to a temporary (an int value returned from `rand()`).  Note that the behavior is undefined, so it might appear to work under some conditions. I tested this program with debug builds on MSVC 2008 and MinGW 4.5.1:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template <class KF, class DT>
class BSTreeNode {

private:
    KF key;
    DT const& dataItem;
    BSTreeNode* left;
    BSTreeNode* right;

public:
    BSTreeNode(KF sKey, DT const &data, BSTreeNode *lt, BSTreeNode *rt)
        : key(sKey)
        , dataItem(data)
        , left(lt)
        , right(rt)
    {}

    void foo() {
        printf( "BSTreeNode::dataItem == %d\n", dataItem);
    } 
};

BSTreeNode<int, int>* test1()
{
    BSTreeNode<int, int>* p = new BSTreeNode<int, int>(5,rand(), NULL, NULL);

    // note: at this point the reference to whatever `rand()` returned in the
    //  above constructor is no longer valid
    return p;
}


int main()
{
    BSTreeNode<int, int>* p1 = test1();

    p1->foo();

    printf( "some other random number: %d\n", rand());

    p1->foo();
}
```

An example run shows:

```
BSTreeNode::dataItem == 41
some other random number: 18467
BSTreeNode::dataItem == 2293724
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Burr. That saved me a lot of time... It was a stupid mistake when I look at it now, but easy to miss.

Comment: can you add a bit more explanation on the lifetime issue?